# Loading Multiple Embedded Single Tweets

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, twitter

I'm trying to load both single tweets and vimeo videos into the same rails app. All the videos are loading great. The issue is with the tweets. Javascript is outside of my knowledge base, but it seems like for embedding tweets that this is the best idea. I'm using the code below that I found [here](https://ctrlq.org/code/19933-embed-tweet-with-javascript)

```
    <script sync src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"></script>

      <script>

        window.onload = (function(){

          var tweet = document.getElementById("tweet");
          var id = tweet.getAttribute("tweetID");

          twttr.widgets.createTweet(
            id, tweet,
            {
              conversation : 'none',    // or all
              cards        : 'visible',  // or visible
              linkColor    : '#ffffff', // default is blue
              theme        : 'dark',    // or dark
              width        : '550', // amount in pixels, between 250 and 550
              align        : 'center' // float the Tweet left, right, or center
            })
          .then (function (el) {
            el.contentDocument.querySelector(".footer").style.display = "none";
          });

        });

    </script>
```

This is what the video block looks like, it seems to be working fine:

```
    <div class="video"> <iframe src="//player.vimeo.com/video/76979871" width="550" height="310" align="center" frameborder="2" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
```

This is the code that I'm using to render the tweets. The problem is that only the first of these tweets is being loaded.

```
    <div id="tweet" tweetID="685974098833313793"></div>

    <div id="tweet" tweetID="672268372868923393"></div>
```

I do understand that there are these problems with the code :1) I'm using the CSS selector id in multiple places, & 2) The javascript is looking for `getElementById`, which in my limited understanding of it means that it's only looking for one tweet id, not all of them on the page.

That said I don't know how to go about changing the js code to made it work.